# CentOS: Can AD id users in domain but AD users can't SSH in

Tags: centos, active-directory, domain

I can join machines to a realm with Ubuntu no problem. So using the exact same steps for CentOS 7.7, I am able to join the domain and id users... but I can't ssh in!

Steps I use only differ with slight difference in package requirements. Here are my CentOS AD join steps:

```
sudo dnf install net-tools samba sssd krb5-workstation krb5-server sssd-krb5 sssd-ad nfs-utils oddjob-mkhomedir

/etc/hostname #contains:
hostname
/etc/hosts #contains:
127.0.0.1 hostname


-set SELINUX to permissive in /etc/selinux/config

Edit /etc/krb5.conf

sudo kinit domain_administrator

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf

systemctl stop sssd

Edit /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

sudo chmod 600 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

sudo net ads join -Udomain_administrator

Add this line to /etc/pam.d/common-session
session    required    pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022

systemctl start sssd

systemctl enable sssd

id moreilly
-Succesfully outputs id info

ssh banana@hostname
Permission denied, please try again.
```

But when I try to su or ssh user@centosbox, it says "Permission denied, please try again."

If I change and enable these lines in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, then I can ssh in BUT no home directory is created:

```
# Kerberos options

#default is no
KerberosAuthentication yes

KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
KerberosTicketCleanup yes

#default no
KerberosGetAFSToken yes

KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes

# DEFAULT IS NO
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
```

Home directory is created automatically on Ubuntu but not on CentOS. Why would I need to go enable these Kerberos and GSSAPI directives in sshd_config for CentOS and not on Ubuntu?

In the end:

1. I dont know why I would need to edit sshd_config on CentOS and not Ubuntu.
2. If I do have to enable these sshd_config directives, then I don't what more to do to get home directories being enabled

Comment: Have you changed the PAM auth configuration?

Comment: @stefan0xC I read about people checking /etc/pam.d/login and  /etc/pam.d/sshd  but those articles were all about pam_Tally and pam_Tally isnt mentioned in either of the files. They also mention, grep sss /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac   and   grep sss /etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac   but both of these files don't contain "sss" at all..

Comment: You don’t want to set the Kerberos options in sshd_config, just gssapi, and certainly not the AFS token option unless you are using OpenAFS. You do want pam_sss in your pam settings, so I’m not sure why you don’t have that

Comment: You should be using pam_oddjob_mkhomedir, which works fine with SELinux (which should be on anyway). See Dan Walsh’s post about it here: https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/69837.html

Answer (score 1):

Place

```
session    required    pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022
```

at the top of all session directives if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Hi thanks. I actually do that already.. but only in /etc/pam.d/common-session. Are there other files to place that directive? Do you know why I would have to enable certain Kerberos and GSSAPI params in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on centos but I dont have to do that on Ubuntu?

Comment: If you do that in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` you need to ensure that the PAM files relating to your login (so `ssh(d)`, for example) include that `common-session` file

Comment: OK. Added session    required    pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022 to  /etc/pam.d/sshd and it works! I still don't understand why between Ubuntu and CentOS I have to make any edits at all to sshd_config however

Comment: /etc/pam.d/common-session is a debianism, and isn’t used at all in a normal CentOS system.  You probably don’t need to make most of the changes you made to sshd_config.